# Sum of multiple columns if they match

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I have this table of data:

```
    A       B       C       D       E
003B1016    1   003G1016    1   003B1016
003G1015    1   003G1391    2   003G1015
003H0121    4   003H6208    2   003H0121
003H6209    1   003H6209    1   003H6209
```

I want to sum B+D if A and C are identical , how would i do that?
I have another 32000 rows of data. :) Thanks for the help

Comment: I believe Sumif will help. For further help please clarify your table structure

Comment: I have tried Sumif but failed because i have single criteria and multiple columns of data. What i need is one criteria and two sum fields

Answer (score 1):

Put this in cell E1 and copy down:

```
=IF(A1=C1,B1+D1,"")
```

This says - if A = C, then add B+D. Otherwise, return blank "".

**EDIT for new requirements**

In order to add all amounts from column B where column A matches the current row and from column D where column C matches that row, where the row in column A exists anywhere and the row in column C exists anywhere, do the following formula in E2 and drag down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,A$1:A1)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,C:C,0)),"",SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)+SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,A2)),"")
```

This says: look above the current row in column A - have we seen this item before? If no, continue with the formula. If yes, ignore, to avoid double counting. Then, Look at all of column C - does the value in the current row of A occur anywhere in column C? If no, then don't add anything. If yes, Add all items from column B where column A matches the current row, and add all items from column D where column C matches the current row.

Comment: Problem being - Column A might have multiple same entries , then i need to sum value based on criteria which is the code in column A. Also Entry in column A might be in row 50,75 and 12005 and Entries in column C might be in rows 20 , 12000 and 25000.

Comment: @Ejmoska That's a very different question from what you originally asked, but take a look at my revised answer.

Comment: i will try this out first thing tomorrow morning at work, sorry for under explaining my question at first

Comment: I have tried your formula and it returned blank spaces, BUT. I have figured it out. I have used the second part of your formula SUMIF+SUMIF. I got all my entries into a list, filtered unique values and used it as criteria =SUMIF($A$2:$A$35000;E2;$B$2:$B$35000)+SUMIF($C$2:$C$35000;E2;$D$2:$D$35000)

Comment: @Ejmoska My formula should return blank spaces for duplicates in column A, or for rows in column A where there is no equivilent value in column C. Note that your version of the formula does not check to confirm that there is a match in column C for a given value in column A.